# Is there a parametric version of lazy `ByteString`?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

My understanding is that `ByteString`s are just lists of vectors of `Word8`s.  This packaging gives better memory and speed performance on binary streams.  Similarly, the `Text` type boosts performance on `Char` streams.

But what if I have `Int` streams, or `Double` streams?  Is there a parametric version of `ByteString` that is easy to use with different data types?  I assume it would only make sense to use on unboxable types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Vector` is the go-to choice for strict arrays. `StorableVector` attempts to be a more `ByteString`-like interface, including lazy, chunked behavior, and I believe was even written originally as a generalization of the `ByteString` code: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/storablevector

Comment: Also, many people use lazy bytestrings and deserialization to obtain lasy streams of `Int`s or `Double`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the "strict" versions use [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.0.1) which is part of the platform.  Vector has both unboxed and (fully generic) boxed variants.  Vector also includes agressive high quality stream fusion.

Comment: I want the lazy version.  Specifically, I want to be able to access a data structure with several gigabytes of `Double`s without loading them all into memory.