# Converting between Storable and Unbox

Tags: haskell, unboxing, storable

Due to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828098/is-there-a-parametric-version-of-lazy-bytestring/16828906?noredirect=1#16828906), I'd like to be able to construct instances of [Foreign.Storable.Storable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Foreign-Storable.html#t:Storable) from instances of [Data.Vector.Unboxed.Unbox](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#t:Unbox) (and vice versa).  Is this possible?

The closest thing I'm aware of is [vector-th-unbox](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox-0.2), but this only creates an unboxable instance.

Answer (score 4):

Check the `vector` package.

Use `Data.Vector.convert :: (Vector v a, Vector w a) => v a -> w a`.

Comment: I can't seem to find the convert function you mention in the [vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.5/doc/html/Data-Vector.html).  Also, based on the type signature I don't see how it would help?

Comment: Look towards the very end of the `Data.Vector` module/documentation.

Comment: All I see is `toList` and `fromList` and a [hoogle search](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=convert) brings up nothing.

Comment: [convert is here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic.html#v:convert)

Answer (score 1):

As *vivian* has already answered you can use the `convert` function that is available in the `Data.Vector.Generic` module: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#v:convert

Comment: (Just noticed that I am a graverobber ... this question is 2 years old now)

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a terribly hacky way to go from unbox to storable, but it is genuinely hacky and inefficient! In fact, having worked through it, I don't actually want to write it out. The notion is that all you can do with an Unbox is work with it in an unboxed vector. Therefore you can initialize an unboxed vector with a singleton element. Given said element, you can create a vector holding it, then pry apart your Vector by evil, and use the bytes directly for your Storable instance. You can equally evilly go the other way.

But I don't know why you'd like to do this. Most data types that are Storable by default are also Unbox and vice versa. And for those that they aren't, deriving Storable is easy enough -- either manually, or with a tool.